# BigDecimal - setar como null pelo formulario quando input estiver vazio

Tags: java, jsf, validação

Tenho um formulário (jsf/primefaces) onde um `value` do tipo `BigDecimal`, pode ser submetido sem valor. Neste caso, o valor dele deverá ser `null`. Entretanto ao ser setado fica como `0`. Há um argumento que é passado para a `vm` pelo `JBOSS` que faz o valor ser setado como `null` mas esta solução não é interessante para mim.

No `web.xml` está definido:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Mas mesmo assim não funciona.

Existe alguma forma de implementar isto continuando o atributo a ser `BigDecimal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa propriedade é para strings vazias.

Para números você precisa setar a propriedade **COERCE_TO_ZERO** como **false**, como diz [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5225055/3293600).

Basta setar a propriedade desta maneira: `System.setProperty("org.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO", "false");`

No lugar correto, como é explicado: em um `ServletContextListener`, para que a propriedade seja setada antes que o `JSF/EL` seja inicializado.